# Add Attributes to root HTML Element of a Custom Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public class CustCtl : WebControl
{
    protected override System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriterTag TagKey
    {
        get
        {
            return HtmlTextWriterTag.Div;
        }
    }       
}
```

With this bare bones control, it would render the root element as a Div tag. But how can I add attributes to that root HTML element that this control will render ... such as a style or id.

Thanks! =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this method while looking at the API.

This worked just fine for me and seemed the most appropriate place to put it. Just simply override.

```
public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "[^_^]");
    base.RenderBeginTag(writer);
}
```

Comment: This method is overriden within the Custom Control. Therefore, when it's RenderBeginTag() is called, I insert attributes as I see fit. What is unclear about the question or my answer?

Comment: sorry, I deleted my comment once I saw that you were the asker. See the comment on my answer...

Answer (score 4):

You would be able to do something like this within the OnPreRender event

```
public class CustCtl : WebControl
{
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        WebControl parent = Parent as WebControl;
        if (parent != null)
        {
            parent.Attributes.Add("key", "value");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for help. Seems a bit easier to do it my way because the intent and meaning is obviously apparent and there is much less work to be done.

Comment: I thought you were trying to add an attribute to the controls parent? I'm going mad because everyone else answered differently, too

Comment: Aah I see. Well interesting how the term "Parent Element" was interpretted as "Parent Control". But apparently I am in the minority on that one. I think HTML when I hear the word element. I rephrased the question to include the word HTML for clarity =D

Answer (score 0):

If you have your `HtmlTextWriter`, you can first add some attributes, before rendering a tag. For example:

```
public void writeDivWithStyle(HtmlTextWriter writer, string style)
{
    writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Style, style);
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);

    // more code here

    writer.RenderEndTag(); // close the DIV
}
```

Comment: "But how can I add attributes to that parent element such as a style or id." am I the only one reading this part?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

`CONTROL.Attribute.Add("..")` //not the correct syntax

see [this link](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/652896-add-div-asp-net-page)

EDIT: sample usage

```
Control control = this.FindControl("body");
HtmlControl divControl = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
divControl.Attributes.Add("id","myid");
divControl.Attributes.Add("class","myclass");
control.Controls.Add(divControl);
```

Comment: Do you want to make me think that passing a single string argument to the Add method, which requires 2 string arguments by the way, points to the **parent control** like a UNIX path?

Comment: Wasn't me, but given what the asker is commenting this is totally valid, aside from the missing params. I read the question differently

Comment: @djechelon: lol, no don't think that..... I edited my answer to show the proper syntax in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit, after all comments] Simply, `Attributes.Add("key", "value");` in `OnPreRender` method works

Comment: The phrasing may be somewhat ambiguous but I disagree as to why.  "With this bare bones control, it would render the **parent element** as a Div tag." The key term is Element in this sentence. I am asking in reference to the parent html element of the control. I did not specify a parent Control in the sentence.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, then option 2 goes for you! ;) I would have said "root element" because just when I read "parent" I think about parent control

Comment: haha understandable. I updated the question heading and body to reflect the more clarified version.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the most appropriate method or event to override is :

```
protected override void AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    writer.AddAttribute("Key", "Value");
    base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);
}
```

Check the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.style.addattributestorender%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).